# How SSR works and how can I achieve it with technologies other than Node.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

Can someone explain what SSR is in more detailed form?

I have searched the web and many of the webpages explaining this concept appear to just phrase "...and SSR is when server renders the page on server".

I can understand what CSR is (rendering the page and creating DOM in the browser when executing the javascript), but I might not have the same depth of understanding with SSR, maybe due to my lack of experience with Node.js. Which I aim to implement the server side with technologies other than Node.js.

It appears to me that with SSR, JavaScript is executed on the server side and first snapshot of the created HTML is sent to the browser? I can see this like when the main JavaScript file is executed and finished executing (when call stack is empty at the end of execution of file), there is already a DOM tree present, and server then creates HTML of this and sends this to the browser? This also means that if there is a function call present such as:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.textContent = "This is a paragraph";
    document.getElementById("myclass").appendChild(p);
}, 0);
```

This "p" element is not present in the initial HTML file. Then JS attaches event handlers etc after this initial page load? Correct me if I am wrong.

**Note**: My main problem is trying to have a SSR application where I can use modern Frontend frameworks such as React without depending on Node.js. I have used create-react-app (CRA) previously to create React app which does many things automatically for the user anyways.

I can write static content directly in HTML, then create and render multiple React roots where the content is dynamic there but I suppose this might not be a good practice in general when initial state of the HTML page have to contain some number of "dynamically creatable" components.

Is there a way to achieve this? I would like to use Java for the backend if possible. But if there are other solutions to this with other backend technologies, I would like to know them as well.

Comment: You got the gist of it right, yep. To achieve SSR in general, your server, well, renders some HTML and sends it to the client instead of just sending an empty page with a script tag that does the work. In this sense, most of the current Internet still is "SSR".

Comment: _"It appears to me that with SSR, JavaScript is executed on the server side"_ - JavaScript is not involved (unless you're using NodeJS/Deno/etc - or various experimental systems from the late-1990s). It's all just plaintext sent as `text/html`.

Comment: @Dai, I have updated my question to add more details to the problem. Please see the "Note" section.

Answer (score 1):

SSR rendering means that the server generates a response e.g. in the form of HTML, that is based on the state given by the HTTP request. That could be a static HTML or something composed a server-side application (Java, PHP, nodejs, ...)
Having SSR is important if you want to support search engines that don't support or penalize client-side only rendering. Or if you want to support visitors that do not have JavaScript active or a slow internet connection.

If you use a client-side framework like React, Vue, Svelte, ... then the SSR has to match a particular form if you want those frameworks to use this SSR as a startingpoint for their setup.

So, if you want to use a particular client-side framework, you need to check what environment they support for SSR or if the environment that you want to use has some third-party support for it.

One thing you could also always do is use the environment that is supported by the framework only for the rendering part. And use the environment you want to use for everything else.

So e.g. write your server in Java, collect all data that is required for SSR, and then pass that to a nodejs server that uses that data for the SSR and returns the generated HTML back to your Java application, which then sends it to the client.